# Why is my preg_replace call only working for characters, not digits?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to update a config file from PHP using regexp. I cant seem to update digits.

This is my `$contents`:

```
$sugar_config['sysconfig_next_order_no'] = 'AAAAA';
$sugar_config['sysconfig_next_quote_no'] = '027827';
```

This is my `$pattern`:

```
/(.*sysconfig_next_order_no']\s=\s')(.*)(';)/
```

---

When I use all letters "AAAAAA" it works -

```
preg_replace($pattern, '$1AAAAAAA$3', $contents);
```

Result:

```
$sugar_config['sysconfig_next_order_no'] = 'AAAAAAA';
$sugar_config['sysconfig_next_quote_no'] = '027827';
```

When I use all numbers, it fails:

```
preg_replace($pattern, '$1123123$3', $contents);
```

Result:

```
23123';
$sugar_config['sysconfig_next_quote_no'] = '027827';
```

Can someone shed some light, I am forcing myself to always use regular expressions.

Comment: Hint: Your replacement string is looking for the 11th capture group, not the 1st one. Your answer lies in the documentation for the `replacement` argument [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: That's because it looks for the **1123123rd** parenthesized group there thanks to `$1123123`.

Comment: AH HA!!!! How do I seperate numbers? ${1}123123$3

Comment: @MichaelJoyner Look toward the bottom of the section in the docs for the `replacement` argument for `preg_replace()`. It's basically the same as PHP's variable variable syntax or the complex syntax for using variables in strings. It uses `{}`. You get the idea? (sorry for the cryptic answers but it's the best way to help you learn :-P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `next_order_no` in your regex - so it is only going to match the text with that key. It is not about numbers or letters - that is the red herring!

Comment: I know I want to update the next_order_no, it works for CHARACTERS not DIGITS